# boto3 get_metric_statistics is always returning empty datapoints

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Getting always empty datapoints (i've checked old post on stackoverflow):

```
cwesponse = cw.get_metric_statistics(
                        Namespace='AWS/EC2',
                        MetricName='CPUUtilization',
                        Dimensions=[
                            {
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': ec2i['InstanceId']
                            },
                        ],
                        StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=14),
                        EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() ,
                        Period=900,
                        Statistics=['Average'],
                        Unit='Percent'
                    )
```

response:

{'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '0820b8e2-c301-41b2-b031-2eb61f9b4c92', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '0820b8e2-c301-41b2-b031-2eb61f9b4c92', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '337', 'date': 'Mon, 20 Dec 2021 22:48:41 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

the same parameters of date and period give me graph on console !

Comment: All parameters seems to be ok. How are you getting the ec2i['InstanceId'] parameter? You can print that value and check if it is correct

Comment: Aren't `StartTime` and `EndTime`  in milliseconds? So you have to multiply your times by 1000.

Comment: @OmarRosadio : yes the parameter ec2i['InstanceId'] is correct , i use it in other api call

Comment: @Marcin : StartTime and EndTime are in iso 8601 format